# Azure Table Storage and ADO.NET for CRUD operations

Tags: azure, ado.net, azure-table-storage

If there is any guidance available on how to use ADO.NET for CRUD Operations on Windows Azure Table Storage?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is difficult to answer because it is too vague. It would be much better to attempt an approach using code, and then ask for help if your approach is unsuccessful. See http://whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table Storage is sometimes a confusing name as it has nothing to do with a relational tables based database like for example SQL Server.

If you want to get your hands dirty with Table Storage then follow [How to Use the Table Storage Service](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/). Another way is to make use of for example [Simple.Data.Azure](https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data.Azure) which you can install as a [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Simple.Data.Azure).

However if you want to keep on making use of ADO.NET to a relational database like you're used to now then take a look at SQL Databases: [How to Use SQL Database in .NET applications](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sql-database/).

Comment: +1 for the pointer to Simple.Data.Azure. Have not tried that yet.

Comment: I recently open sourced, Lucifure Stash, (http://lucifurestash.codeplex.com/)) an alternate azure table storage client which has many more features. Available from NuGet too.

Comment: @Lucifure Cool, will have to take a look at that in the future.